# Distintos resultados al usar diferentes formas de recorrer un array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, iteraciones

El propósito de mi programa es crear dos funciones, `some()` y `every()`, que emulan a las funciones `Array.prototype.some()` y `Array.prototype.every()`, respectivamente.

Mi código:

```
function every(array, callback) {
    array.forEach(function(element) {
        if (!callback(element)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

function everyB(array, callback) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!callback(array[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function everyC(array, callback) {
    for (element of array) {
        if (!callback(element)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Estas son las 3 versiones que he realizado al comprobar que tras ejecutar:

```
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
```

el resultado es `true`, mientras que:

```
console.log(everyB([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
```

y

```
console.log(everyC([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
```

devuelven `false`, que es lo correcto.

Lo único que varía entre estas 3 funciones son los tipos de iteración utilizados 
para recorrer el array, y no encuentro el motivo por el cual `every()` no funciona como es esperado.

*Documentación:*

- [Array.prototype.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/every)
- [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/some)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es simple , el método [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) no tiene valor de retorno [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/undefined).

En la documentación "especifica" este comportamiento.

> No hay forma de detener o cortar un bucle forEach que no sea lanzar
>   una excepción. Si necesita dicho comportamiento, el método .forEach()
>   **es la herramienta equivocada**

Por lo cuál jamás realizará la línea `return false;` , no se cortará la iteración y por lo tanto siempre se ejecutará el `return true;`

Comment: Vale, qué fallo mas tonto. No había caído, gracias.